# Reduce Android App Storage Size built through MAUI

Tags: android, maui

I built a basic android app that takes some inputs from the user, does some calculations and displays the output.

But the final size of the application is turning out to be 114MB, which is huge. :(

I tried deleting the user data by clicking on Clear Storage, but then I am unable to start the app itself.

Can someone help me with a way to reduce the app storage size?

[image]

Comment: You can use adb to view what is being stored in your apps user folders

Comment: *"the final size of the application is turning out to be 114MB"* But `App size` is only `18.15 MB`. That's what determines download time and bandwidth. Looking at my cheap Android device, there are apps I've *never used* with a Total Size over 100MB. Apps I have used, get much larger than that. Are you sure that size is unacceptable?

Comment: I see my most used apps like GPay, Ola, etc., are also taking ~110MB. Relatively this is a very basic application. It's not completely unacceptable, but I am guessing that there must be a way to reduce that size.

Comment: Did you try to run the project in the release mode?

Comment: https://medium.com/@freakyali/reducing-app-size-in-net-maui-a4724cc0a36#:~:text=If%20possible%20always%20use%20D8,better%20performance%20and%20app%20size.

Answer (score 0):

> I am unable to start the app itself

This must be some crash, read the log and solve it.

As for reduce app storage size, you can find all the directories you used, and  make a clean cache entrance for user to clean the cache by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

[Change from Debug to Release in Visual Studio in Project and start Debugging.
App will be 50-70 mb and user data will be 0.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPhH5.png)